# 'collect' action not displaying result in driver window for Spark standalone application

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am using Spark 1.4.0 on my local system. Whenever I create an RDD and call collect on it through Scala shell of Spark, it works fine. But when I create a standalone application and call 'collect' action on the RDD, I don't see the result , despite the Spark messages during the run say that certain number of bytes have been set to driver:-

```
INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 1991 bytes result sent to driver
INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 1948 bytes result sent to driver
```

This is the code:-

```
object Test
{   def main(args:Array[String]) 
    {
        val conf = new SparkConf()      
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val rdd1 = sc.textFile("input.txt")
        val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_.split(",")).map(x=>( (x(0),x(1)) ))
        rdd2.collect
    }   

}
```

If I change the last statement to the following, it does display the result:-

```
rdd2.collect.foreach(println)
```

So the question is, why only calling 'collect' does not print anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collect` by itself on a console app would not display anything as all it does is return the data. You have to do something to display it, as you are doing with the `foreach(println)`. Or, do something with it in general, like saving it to disk.

Now, if you were to run that code in the `spark-shell` (minus `SparkContext` creation), then you would indeed see output* as the shell always calls the `toString` of the objects that are returned.

*Noting that `toString` is not the same as `foreach(println)` since the shell would truncate at some point